# react state array object is not accessible in render() method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Hi i have this wierd problem in which i can access property `ooPP`on state object but can not access property `data` of state objects. the only difference is how they are populated.

- `state.ooPP` is hardcoded
- `state.data` is set after calling few functions .

i can see value of `state.data` as array with one element in `react native dev tools` but why is `this.state.data` null in `render()`?

here is the code:

```
   export default class HomeScreen extends Component {

      _retrieveData = async key => {
        try {
          const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);
          if (value !== null) {
            // We have data!!
            console.log("yay....", value);
            return value;
          }
        } catch (error) {
          // Error retrieving data
        }
      };

      getAllKeys = async () => {
        let keys = [];
        try {
          keys = await AsyncStorage.getAllKeys();
        } catch (e) {
          // read key error
        }

        return keys;
      };



      constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          data:[],
          kk:'oo',
          ooPP:[{'username':'uuuuu'}]
        }

        this.getAllKeys().then(keys => {
          var promises = keys.map(key => {
            return this._retrieveData(key)
              .then(value => {
                console.log(value, "xx");
                return JSON.parse(value);
              })
              .catch(error => {
//
              });
          });

          Promise.all(promises)
            .then(results => {
              this.state.data=results
            })
            .catch(e => {
//
            });
        });
      }



      renderSeparator = () => {
        return (
          <View
            style={{
              height: 1,
              backgroundColor: "#CED0CE"
            }}
          />
        );
      };

      render = () => {
        return (
          <View>
            <FlatList
              data={this.state.data} //-------> this is not accessible
              ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
              renderItem={({ item }) => (
                <TOTPItem value={item.username} time={(20 / 30) * 100} />
              )}
            />
            <Text>dd {this.state.kk}</Text>
          </View>
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: If you don't use `setState` like you're supposed to, React isn't going to re-render the component. You're still changing `this.state` obviously, because React is just JavaScript, but if you insist on ignoring the docs, don't expect React to behave as expected.

Comment: @ChrisG i am  not ignoring the docs. i started react native/react learning today.also i am a backend dev so i just missed it. anyways thannks for help its working now :)

Comment: I was responding to `i am updating state in constructor so setState() is not the correct way` but I see now where the confusion was coming from :)

Answer (score 3):

```
Promise.all(promises)
  .then(results => {              
    this.setState({data: results});
  })
  .catch(e => {
    //
  });
});
```

You need to use `setState` to update state.

Comment: i am updating state in constructor so setState() is not the correct way. also if state is not updated then how is it visible in dev tools?

Comment: holy cow! thanks. this is working. i had been scratching my head for entire day before giving up on this.

Comment: In constructor, we just initialize the state variable. we do not update there. Use `ComponentDidMount()`  to update state.

Comment: Of note: `setState` is an async action, so after it returns, the state is not guaranteed to have changed yet. If you need to wait on the state to change, then pass a callback to `setState`. This would be especially important if you were to continue chaining promises after `setState`...